# The server tag is not well formed error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this code. The code contains the expected runat="server" attribute, but it is giving me this error message: `error on hiddenfield` part.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value="<%#Eval("Path")%>" runat="server" />
        <img alt="image" style="text-align: center" src="<%#Eval("Path")%>" /><asp:CheckBox
            ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <br></br>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You have a closing `</a>` - but no opening `<a href=.....> ` ...

Comment: you cannot assign ID's in a repeater it creates multiple elements with the same id, which leads to unexpected behavior. to prevent this ASP might throw an error

Comment: I forgot to delete it the point is not this

Comment: @Vogel612 That isn't true and ASP will not throw an error. You can assign an ID just fine and they will all come out unique. This is helpful in finding controls during DataBound events. Can see in [MSDN Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), as well as just general use.

Comment: @Vogel612 The only time IDs would be the same is if there is no `runat="server"` on the control.

Comment: check all the properties of elements.They may have no space between them.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You could not use double quotes within double quotes so use combination of *single* and *double* `quotes`.

*Change*

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value="<%#Eval("Path")%>" runat="server" />
```

*To*

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("Path")%>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: @calypso The 2nd quote in your example is technically the "end quote" meaning your value is `Value="<%#Eval("` immediately followed by `Path")%>"'` with no space. Same error as if you did `ID="_me"runat="server"`

Comment: If the value of the parameter itself contains quotes (ex. a javascript function call containing a string), you MUST use single quotes to encapsulate the value, and use double quotes within the value to encapsulate any contained strings.

Comment: That was certainly maddening enough.  Pretty cool that this came up as the first hit on my search!

Answer (score 6):

Try using single quotes instead of double quotes when using an eval scriptlet, like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("Path")%>' runat="server" />
        <img alt="image" style="text-align: center" src='<%#Eval("Path")%>' /></a><asp:CheckBox
            ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <br></br>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I really don't understand the reasoning why this is required, but that is what works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error because of **quotes** and this is how I fixed mine

```
    OnClientClick='<%# "CallToFunc("+ Eval("Val") + 
    ",\"" + Eval("StringVal")  + "\");return false;"'
```

Comment: Speaking of quotes, there is no closing quote for the single quote.

Comment: Right! thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `runat` inside of a html comment.

(Not the problem of this question, but it matches the title of this question)

Suppose you have an ASP control that you want to "comment out", then you might end up with a page that cannot show at all, with, if you are lucky, the "server tag is not well-formed" exception, or with a simple 404-not found status code.

Fix: change the runat e.g. like this:

```
<!-- asp.Label   runatX="server" ... -->
```