# Js function call with param on HyperLink

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function

I am trying to call my js function on a HyperLink that needs RowID as a parameter and I cant do it!

I have try a lot of ways but always i get null.

How I can achieve this?

```
<script>
        var popUpObj;

        function RowClick(filterId) {

            popUpObj = window.open("voucher.aspx?param=" + filterId + "",
             "ModalPopUp",
             "toolbar=no," +
             "scrollbars=no," +
             "location=no," +
             "statusbar=no," +
             "menubar=no," +
             "resizable=0," +
             "width=530," +
             "height=500," +
             "left = 450," +
             "top=130"
            );
             popUpObj.focus();
             LoadModalDiv();


         }
    </script>



 <MasterTableView ClientDataKeyNames="RowID" AllowPaging="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="RowID" AllowCustomPaging="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True"   >
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="RowID" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowID column" HeaderText="RowID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RowID" UniqueName="RowID" Visible="False">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

     <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowID column" UniqueName="RowID" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:RowClick()"  Text="Add voucher link"></asp:HyperLink>

                             </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: you call `"javascript:RowClick()" ` without params, so sure you have `filterId` param _undefined_. How you try pass parameter?

Comment: Yes with javascript:RowClick(RowID) and still null

Comment: where you get `RowID`?

Comment: ClientDataKeyNames="RowID"

Comment: so you just write `NavigateUrl="javascript:RowClick(RowID)"`? _NavigateUrl_ is just string, and it rendered as is, so in html you have something like `<a href="javascript:RowClick(RowID)">` and sure it not work

Comment: if i make a line with      <asp:Label ID="RowID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RowID") %>'></asp:Label> i am getting the rowid fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78763/discussion-between-grundy-and-marios).

Comment: Use client side events of Telerik grid and handle the click event

Comment: possible duplicate of [The server tag is not well formed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278616/the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fix your error with *The server tag is not well formed error* you should use single quotes for attribute values, and make navigate url inside binding

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("javascript:RowClick({0})",Eval("RowID"))%>'  Text="Add voucher link"></asp:HyperLink>
```

But in case when you need simple link, methinks better use just *a* tag, something like

```
<a href="javascript:RowClick('<%# Eval("RowID") %>')" >Add voucher link</a>
```

in my opinion it easy and more readable

Answer (score 1):

Use LinkButton instead of HyperLink. See example below.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn" Text="Add voucher link" runat="server" 
 OnClientClick='<%# "RowClick(" + Eval("RowID") + "); return false;" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Edited the LinkButtoncontrol. Use the example as a guide.

Comment: still : Uncaught ReferenceError: filterId is not defined