# Eval Check String Null or Empty

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Account Name">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblRecieverClientAccountName" runat="server" 
              Text='<%#Eval("RecieverClientAccountName").ToString()) ? 
               String.Empty : 'Invalid Account number'
               ,"RecieverClientAccountName" %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I need  to check  string is empty and show  a custom message .It gives me an error "The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: the problem is .ToString(). You should check it before .ToString() function.

Comment: That is not legal C#, what kind of **character** is this? `'Invalid Account number'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The server tag is not well formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278616/the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed-error)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `.ToString()`. You should check it before `.ToString()` function

Try as below

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRecieverClientAccountName" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("RecieverClientAccountName")) ? 
           String.Empty : 'Invalid Account number'
           ,"RecieverClientAccountName" %>'></asp:Label>
```

Or check it for `null` values.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRecieverClientAccountName" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("RecieverClientAccountName"))==
          null : 'Invalid Account number'
           ,"RecieverClientAccountName" %>'></asp:Label>
```

**I have not tested it so far.**

### Edit 1

Try this

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("RecieverClientAccountName").ToString()) ?...
```

Similar Question on SO [Using '<%# Eval("item") %>'; Handling Null Value and showing 0 against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979806/using-evalitem-handling-null-value-and-showing-0-against)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Account Name">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblRecieverClientAccountName" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("RecieverClientAccountName") ? 
           String.Empty : 'Invalid Account number, ' +
           Eval("RecieverClientAccountName") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRecieverClientAccountName" runat="server" 
           Text='<%#Eval("RecieverClientAccountName")) ?
           "" : 'Invalid Account number'
           ,"RecieverClientAccountName" %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had error: "The server tag is not well formed." because of:

```
'Invalid Account number'
```

you have to change it to:

```
"Invalid Account number"
```

You can use Eval function like this:

```
Eval("RecieverClientAccountName") == null ? "" : Eval("RecieverClientAccountName").ToString()
```

or

```
Eval("RecieverClientAccountName") == DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("RecieverClientAccountName").ToString()
```

Answer (score -1):

Check Eval values Null or Not Null

```
<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("RecieverClientAccountName").ToString())?  "Null" : "Values" %>
```

Comment: Exception happens at .ToString() if Eval("ReceiverClientAccountName") is null.

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("RecieverClientAccountName").ToString()) here i am checking the values is null or not null and it is not posible to happen error