# Text in hyperlink throwing an error on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set the text of a hyperlink with some data I'm retrieving from the database but its throwing the following error:

> The server tag is not well formed.

I'm new to asp. What tags am I missing from the line below?

```asp
<asp:Repeater ID="Rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p> <span><%# Eval("Name") %>
        <asp:HyperLink  ID="Url" runat="server" Text ="<%# Eval("Url") %>"/>  </span></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

error is thrown on this line:

```asp
<asp:HyperLink  ID="Url" runat="server" Text ="<%# Eval("Url") %>"/>
```

I'm not sure on how to format the tags here. Please help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You use double quotes with your Eval Tag. Use single quotes instead

```
Text ='<%# Eval("Url") %>'/>
```

The way you do it you finish your `Text` attribute too early

Answer (score 0):

Your missing `<span>` opening tag. Use this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><span><%# Eval("Name") %>
        <asp:HyperLink  ID="Url" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Url") %>'/>  </span></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**After edit question Use single quote instead of double for text property. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278641/4165839